# How to specify the left, right, or title View button in XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

1. I do not want to create a custom navigation bar.
2. I am pushing a UIViewController and I want to customize how the navigation bar looks for that UIViewController

In story board, we just specify the segue and a nav bar show up on the screen. We just drag and drop UIBarItem to the left and right.

In XIB, the navigationBar simply doesn't show up.

I can add navigation Item but the one I added is ignored.

I've heard that there used to be an outlet called navigationItem but it's deprecated for reason I do not know.
I can add UINavigationBar, however that would be adding my own custom bar. I want the navBar that's provided by UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the actual way apple want this to be implemented.

Put UINavigationBar

Set outlet to the UINavigationItem

This is the catch

Override navigationItem property to return the UINavigationItem you created.

That's it.

```
-(UINavigationItem *) navigationItem
{
    return self.navigationItem1;
}
```

If your navigationItem is still in the UINavigationBar, I think you will need to have a strong outlet to the UINavigation Bar too. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

The appearance of the Navigation Bar in the storyboard designer is just there to illustrate how your screen will look when you load your ViewController inside a `UINavigationController`.  It doesn't mean that you actually have a navigation controller in your app.

You need to add a `UINavigationController` to your storyboard (probably as the first scene), and then connect your ViewController to it (as the root view controller).

Then you should be able to set your title in the storyboard designer, and drag bar button items onto the navigation bar.

See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979705/linking-uinavigationcontroller-in-storyboard-to-appdelegate).

Comment: I know. That's not what I am asking. I am asking how to set that items through XIB. Not simple. I've looked around. No easy answer.

Comment: Also even if it's just there to illustrate, I can indeed add left and right button there.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup it in code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Title";
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = "Create button" ;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  "Create button" ;
    self.navigationItem.titleView =  "Create custom title view";
}
```

Comment: I know how to set that up in code, I want to know how to set that up in XIB the right way